# Problem with slideUp/slidedown in a if statement -jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slidedown, slideup

I have a problem regarding accordion effect I want to make.

I would like to have following functionality - If you press anywhere in "div.post" the text surrounded in "p.read-more", which is hidden from start, slides down and reveal itself. Then to close it, you need to press "div.close".

I have tried something like this, but frankly, as you probably can see, I'm lost :-)

This is the HTML

```
<div class="post">
    <p>This is a beginning of a text.</p>
    <p class="read-more">... This is the rest of the text</p>
    <div class="close">This is a close button</div>
</div>
```

I have tried something like this

```
$("p.read-more").hide();

$('div.post').click(function(){         
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
});

if( $('div.post').hasClass('active') ) {
    $('div.close').click(function(){
        $(this).find(".read-more").slideUp();        
    }); 

} else {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).find(".read-more").slideDown();
    });
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Sorry I misunderstood exactly what you wanted to happen:

> I would like to have following functionality - If you press anywhere
>   in "div.post" the text surrounded in "p.read-more", which is hidden
>   from start, slides down and reveal itself. Then to close it, you need
>   to press "div.close".

This click event basically says 'if div.post DOESN'T have the active class then slide down .read-more and add the active class to div.post'.

```
$('div.post').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('p.read-more').slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

The div.close event is simple - there is no condition as if you fire the event when .read-more is already hidden nothing will happen anyway!

**UPDATE**

```
$('div.close').click(function() {
    $('p.read-more').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $('div.post').removeClass('active');
    );        
}
```

This should be all you need to achieve what you seek. And as another thought I would say don't hide the .read-more using jQuery just do it using CSS - that way you won't get a flicker when the page loads.

Comment: Thank you for the pointing out the typo, It's fixed now. Problem with this solution is that div.post still has the click function running when its active, I would like to disable it so the user needs to use the close button to close the box.

Comment: You don't actually need to disable it - you can just have a conditional check in the event to see if the div has the active class - have a look at my updated answer I think it should be correct

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's nearly there! But after I press the close div the box slides up and directly after, it slides down. A conflict in the code?

Comment: ahh yes it is because when you are clicking div.close it is within div.post so div.post click event is also firing, I'll update the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="post">
    <p>This is a beginning of a text.</p>
    <p class="read-more">... This is the rest of the text</p>
    <div class="close">This is a close button</div>
</div>
```

It looks like you're missing the closing div on the 4th line.

---

A simpler version of the jquery you can use is

```
$("p.read-more").hide();

$('div.post').click(function(){  
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) return; //exits function if this is already active

    $(".read-more").slideUp();   //causes all section to slide up
    $(this).find(".read-more").slideDown();  //causes only selected section to slide down
    $(".read-more").removeClass("active");    //removes active class from everything
    $(this).find(".read-more").addClass("active");  //sets active class to current item
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the typo is fixed. Can I disable the click function when the post is active? I would like to force the user to use the close div to the close the box.

Comment: I updated my post. For the close button, you can probably use   $(this).parent().slideUp(); or something similar, depending on the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. What's tripping you up here is the sequence of operations. Your if statement is run once when the script is parsed. You want your slide animations to run after a click event, so they need to be moved to the click handler.

```
$('div.post').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).find(".read-more").slideDown();
});
```

And then modify your `close` click handler to look for its `read-more` to toggle

```
$('div.close').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings(".read-more").slideUp();

    e.stopPropagation();    // This prevents the div.post click from firing
});
```

Also, there is a syntax error in your html. Not sure if that's a typo or not. Your `close` div's end tag is missing.

Comment: Sorry for the syntax error, I have updated the html. I've tried this code, but its seems that the click function for div.post still is active after the click.